# groovy replace double quotes with single and single with double

Tags: groovy, quotes

I have a string `"['type':'MultiPolygon', 'coordinates':[[73.31, 37.46], [74.92, 37.24]]]"`

How can I replace all single quotes with double quotes and double to with single?
The result should be like this:
`'["type":"MultiPolygon", "coordinates":[[73.31, 37.46], [74.92, 37.24]]]'`

Comment: ..and why is that needed, if I may know?

Comment: as an input for one web service

Comment: check the [replace methods](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html) in the groovy docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [link](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html) given by @yate, you can find a method:

```
tr(String sourceSet, String replacementSet)
```

and apply that to your string as:

```
def yourString = ...
def changedString = yourString.tr(/"'/,/'"/)
```

that will do the job.

Comment: Probably looks nice using slash strings `str.tr( /'"/, /"'/ )`

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [replaceAll](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.util.regex.Pattern,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29) method.  Since the first conversion will be overridden by the second, you may need a temporary variable:

```
String replacePlaceholder = '%%%' // Some unlikely-to-occur value
yourString = yourString.replaceAll('\'', replacePlaceholder)
    .replaceAll('"', '\'')
    .replaceAll(replacePlaceholder, '"')
```

It's certainly not the most efficient way to do it, but it's a start.